# how to perform Condition check, before segue unwind

Tags: ios, swift

`VC1` segues to `VC3` which has a keypad and predetermined lowest number acceptable entered into a label. User can either add a number to the end of this string or delete a number. When "Accept" key is pressed, the string.toInt() is passed to `VC1` and segue is unwind via

```
@IBAction func unwindToSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:UIStoryboardSegue){
    BetLabels[betSourceR].text = BetReturned
    if BetReturned == ""{} else{
        Chip[betSourceR].hidden = false}}
```

I need to achieve so that no string.toInt() lower than minimum is accepted and some sort of override func that stops the unwind from happening while posting a warning to the user that this input is not acceptable.

How would i achieve this when?
 **Maybe place something in `VC3` func prepareForsegue? Or another method?**

Or could i disconnect the "accept" from the unwind, and make a IBAction that if under minimum{ warn user, return to VC3} else {VC1.unwindToSegue}

Comment: Why don't you check the value before you try to execute the segue?

Comment: thats what I want to do. But since its tied to a `func unwindToSegue` I'm not sure how to perform this check.

Comment: Make the segue from the controller instead of the accept button, so you can call performSegueWithIdentifier when your conditions are met.

Comment: could you explain further how to do this? Also this won't create a cyclic segue? I read that unwind should always be used when backtracking through viewController hierarchy so that it won't just load VC ontop of VC until memory is overloaded.

Comment: or I could make the "Accept" only visible when condition is met!!

Comment: You would still use an unwind. There's no difference between an unwind segue made from a button vs. making it from the controller. You just drag from the controller icon to the exit icon to create it. The main difference is that you have to call perform Segue, it doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: okay so I connect controller to unwind...make the accept button an IBAction which checks condition, if not met...A Warning...if met {what code would go here to performSegueWithIdentifier}

Comment: Give the segue an identifier in the storyboard, and then just do preformSegueWithIdentifier("Whatever", sender: self)

Comment: okay ty, would you like to post this as an answer so you get credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, connect `Controller` of `VC3` to its own exit and select the unwind action.

Give this exit-segue a `segue.identifier` "YOUR EXIT TEXT"

Still in `VC3`, create an `IBAction` for the "Accept" button.

```
@IBAction func accept(sender: AnyObject) {
    if //Condition X is true
        {performSegueWithIdentifier("YOUR EXIT TEXT", sender: self)}
    else {
        //Do this
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a good answer in this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883050/swift-prepareforsegue-cancel).

The trick is to override **shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier** in VC3. Inside it, you can place your condition check and return false in case the segue should be stopped. Otherwise, return true to make the segue happen. Here is a sample code for your case.

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    if identifier == "submitUnwindSegue"{
        if string.toInt() < minimum {
            //fire an alert controller about the error
            return false
        }
    }

    //Continue with the segue
    return true
```