# Use ShouldPerformSegue to cancel a segue created in a storyboard

Tags: swift, macos, segue

I have a segue I created using my storyboard and under certain conditions I do not want the segue to execute.

The visual representation of the segue and my add button

[image: The visual representation of the segue and my add button]

The segue connected to the action of my button

[image: The segue connected to the action of my button]

The segue's identifier

[image: The segue's identifier]

Comment: Do you also want to disable the button so the user won't hit it again and again?

Comment: In a complete real world situation I would disable the button when the view controller is created, and look at the count to determine if the button should be enabled. Then in the delegate callback for a created account it would enable the button if the accounts is greater than zero.

Comment: How is the segue executed if the button is disabled?

Comment: It wouldn’t be. This is only a example of how to decide in code to either execute or not execute a segue. I created the example because the question come up for me and I didn’t see an answer here and I figured I would share. Nothing more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift prepareForSegue cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883050/swift-prepareforsegue-cancel)

Comment: Not entirely but it is very similar. The example there looks like it is all through code while this is a example that works through the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is in the NSViewController of the button triggering the segue override shouldPerformSegue and perform your check in there to determine if the segue should be executed.

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier, sender: Any?) -> Bool
{
    var result = false
    if identifier == "AddPayeeSegue"
    {
        if AccountingData.instance.book.account.count > 0
        {
                result = true
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

Comment: That was a strange copy and paste error, sorry. I corrected it.